# how to change style of primefaces component

Tags: css, primefaces

how change the style of primefaces components.
especially the background color of `<p:layoutUnit`.

this is my code :

```
<p:layout fullPage="true">
        <!-- TITRE -->
        <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="auto" resizable="true" closable="true"  >
            <ui:include src="titre.xhtml"></ui:include>
        </p:layoutUnit>
        <!-- CONTENT -->
        <p:layoutUnit position="center" size="25%" header="Options" >
                <ui:include src="titre.xhtml"></ui:include>
        </ui:include>
    <p:layout fullPage="true">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add: style="background: red !important" for red background. You can also roll out your own theme. The process is described in the primefaces manual (available for free online):

```
<p:layoutUnit position="north" style="background: red !important;" size="auto" resizable="true" closable="true"  >
```

If you need something more specific- feel free to ask.

Comment: thx for response. I tried it. but the problem only the border of <p:layoutUnit who changes to red color. I want to change the primefaces theme of my aplication

Comment: Oh, I forgot about this. You also need to style: ui-layout-unit div.ui-layout-unit-content to get the color to change. If you want to style the whole theme- in the documentation they describe how to do it with theme roller. The link: http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/primefaces_users_guide_3_4.pdf